# How to style li, span, and a elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

Sorry for any formatting issues or if questions like these are not allowed, first time posting on here. This project was submitted as pictured as I couldn’t get it to look correctly in time for the assignment due date. I’d really just like some explanation or direction, as I’m really interested in HTML/CSS and would like to understand everything I’m doing wrong, unfortunately no solutions are posted for these projects. My code and project steps posted below.
**I struggled specifically in questions 6-9**

output vs my output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJuff.jpg

**1)** Remember that all gradients are treated as **background-images**(so you can use background repeat, etc in a gradient)

**2)** The **scroll div** element contains two spheres(**left** and **right floated).**
a)Each **sphere** has a **width** of 15 pixels and a **height** of 30 pixels with a **border radius** of 50% and a **radial gradient color** of **white** (center) then tan.

b)To ensure that the **sphere** is on top of the **linear gradient**,you need to adjust the **linear gradient** so that it will not go beyond the **sphere**.That is,the scroll must have a **height** of 30 pixels and a **width** of 640 pixels.

The gradient goes like this:

i)The **background image** is a l**inear gradient** of tan then antiquewhite and then tan.

ii)Its background position is center.

iii) It doesn’t repeat.

iv) The background size is set to be smaller than the element’s size,e.g.background-size has a height of 20 pixels and a width of 620 pixels so that the it will be behind the two spheres.

**3)** The ul element,which has no markers, has a padding of 0 and then it needs to be shifted upwards.To do so,the ul element must use a relative position and then has a top attribute of -5 pixels. I make ul element to be 600 pixels so that it’s slightly narrower than the top and bottom scrolls.The margins are also auto for everything in order to center the scrolls.

**4)** The ul element must look like an old scroll,so you will need to use a linear gradient of tan, antiquewhite, then four whites,then back to antiquewhite,and then tan.In addition,the ul element has left and right borders of 3 pixels, styles of ridge,and colors of tan.

**5)** Each li element uses a line height and font size of 14 pixels and have text shadow of darkgoldenrod color with 0 offsets and 10 pixels blurs.It has a left and right margin of 20 pixels as well as top and bottom paddings of 4 pixels.

**6)** Now,we will look into our li elements,where there are dots between the span and a element,just like the dots in the normal table of contents. That is, we will apply the following to the background of the li element:

a)A background image of linear gradient to the right:two transparent colors, one black color, and then two transparent colors.

b)The background has a width of 4 pixels and a height of 1 pixel.

c)The background only repeats in the x-direction.

d)The background is centered.

**7)** Within each li element, we have a span element and an anchor (a) element, which are floated left and right, respectively.They are both of inline-block displays and have no underlines.To hide the dots in these elements, we will need to recolor those dots with the same colors. That is, they will have similar styles as the dots:

a)The background has a width of 4 pixels and a height of 1 pixel.

b)The background only repeats in the x-direction.

c)The background is centered.

d)They are all linear gradient, such as linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #ffffff);

e)In addition,because the scroll has different colors,we define the colors in the following order:

i)#e4ccad(Tutorial 1)

ii)#fcf2e4(Tutorial 2)

iii)White for Tutorials 3—6

iv)#fbf1e3(Tutorial 7)

v)#e2cbab(Tutorial 8).

**8)** Each li element has a hover (li:hover) that has a background color of tan; the background image of all the children elements in the hover will override the linear gradient as shown above: linear-gradient(to right, tan, tan)—so that the dots are also hidden there.

**9)** Finally,the last scroll element has a relative position,shifted top by a few pixels(-12pixels).

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/*
Date: 10/31/20

*/

/*Body Styles*/

body{
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    
}
/*Scroll Styles*/

div.scroll {
    height: 30px;
    width: 640px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(tan, antiquewhite, tan);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 620px 30px;
}

/*Sphere Styles*/

div.sphere1 {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(white, tan);
    
}
div.sphere2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(white, tan);
}
/*ul Styles*/

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: 600px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(tan, antiquewhite, white, white, white, white, antiquewhite, tan);
    border-style: ridge;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-color: tan;
}
/*List Styles*/

ul li{
    line-height: 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: 0, 0, 10px, darkgoldenrod;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, transparent, black, transparent, transparent);
    background-size: 4px 1px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
}
span a {
    float: left;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-size: 4px 1px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
}
ul.span  {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e4ccad);
}
span
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scroll"><div class="sphere1"></div><div class="sphere2"></div></div>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Getting Started with HTML 5.</span><a href="#t1">Tutorial 1</a></li>
        <li><span>Getting Started with CSS.</span><a href="#t2">Tutorial 2</a></li>
        <li><span>Designing a Page Layout.</span><a href="#t3">Tutorial 3</a></li>
        <li><span>Graphic Design with CSS.</span><a href="#t4">Tutorial 4</a></li>
        <li><span>Designing for the Mobile Web.</span><a href="#t5">Tutorial 5</a></li>
        <li><span>Working with Tables and Columns.</span><a href="#t6">Tutorial 6</a></li>
        <li><span>Designing a Web Form</span><a href="#t7">Tutorial 7</a></li>
        <li><span>Enhancing a Website with Multimedia.</span><a href="#t8">Tutorial 8</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="scroll"><div class="sphere1"></div><div class="sphere2"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and change color based on your actual preference.

```
ul{
list-style-type:none;
}

li{
display:block;
}

ul li a:hover{
color:#332419;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
}

li:hover{
background-color:#ead6b7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given a very long description. I have tried to replicate the image you have given.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/*
Date: 10/31/20

*/

/*Body Styles*/

body{
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    
}
/*Scroll Styles*/

div.scroll {
    height: 30px;
    width: 640px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(tan, antiquewhite, tan);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 620px 30px;
}

/*Sphere Styles*/

div.sphere1 {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(white, tan);
    
}
div.sphere2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(white, tan);
}
/*ul Styles*/

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: 600px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(tan, antiquewhite, white, white, white, white, antiquewhite, tan);
    border-style: ridge;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-color: tan;
}
/*List Styles*/

ul li{
    line-height: 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: 0, 0, 10px, darkgoldenrod;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

li:hover{
    background-color: tan;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
ul.span  {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e4ccad);
}
.placeholder{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, transparent, black, transparent, transparent);
    background-size: 4px 1px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scroll"><div class="sphere1"></div><div class="sphere2"></div></div>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Getting Started with HTML 5.</span><span class="placeholder"></span><a href="#t1">Tutorial 1</a></li>
        <li><span>Getting Started with CSS.</span><span class="placeholder"></span><a href="#t2">Tutorial 2</a></li>
        <li><span>Designing a Page Layout.</span><span class="placeholder"></span><a href="#t3">Tutorial 3</a></li>
        <li><span>Graphic Design with CSS.</span><span class="placeholder"></span><a href="#t4">Tutorial 4</a></li>
        <li><span>Designing for the Mobile Web.</span><span class="placeholder"></span><a href="#t5">Tutorial 5</a></li>
        <li><span>Working with Tables and Columns.</span><span class="placeholder"></span><a href="#t6">Tutorial 6</a></li>
        <li><span>Designing a Web Form</span><span class="placeholder"></span><a href="#t7">Tutorial 7</a></li>
        <li><span>Enhancing a Website with Multimedia.</span><span class="placeholder"></span><a href="#t8">Tutorial 8</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="scroll"><div class="sphere1"></div><div class="sphere2"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```